# How to get message from server after upload the file in silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I followed the example to upload files to the server successfully:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/FileUploadsilverlight03182009030537AM/FileUploadsilverlight.aspx

Is it possible to get a string message from the server on the webclient `OpenWriteCompleted` event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of a number of bizare design choices for the Silverlight WebClient, you can't access the Response easily having performed a POST.  Its really odd since most POST operations have a useful response body.

However there are a number of things you can do.  You could ditch the `WebClient` and use `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` directly.  You could inherit off the `WebClient` and override `GetWebResponse` so you can intercept it.

However a sneaky option if your string message is reasonably short is to add a custom HTTP header to the response.

The thread executing OpenWriteCompleted will block when the output stream is closed until a response is received.  At that point you can access the `ResponseHeaders` collection on the `WebClient` object to retrieve the value of your custom header.  (Why the Response stream hasn't been made available at the point escapes me!)

Comment: Can you introduce more detail that how to add a "custom HTTP header" in the ashx file? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

On your `HttpHandler` you'll just need

```
context.Response.Write("You made it");
```

To read it on Silverlight side, you'll probably need to deal with `OpenReadCompleted` event.

Comment: OpenReadCompleted only fires when OpenReadAsync is used.